# How can I avoid the error TCP_MISS_ABORTED/000 when uploading files through squid?

Tags: linux, tcp, squid, upload, bug

While uploading big files, > 10MB, through a squid V5.6, I noticed that they failed and/or were retried.

The error has been logged multiple times in the logs:

```
1671092710.452    423 ::1 TCP_MISS_ABORTED/000 0 PUT http://YOUR_URL - FIRSTUP_PARENT/YOUR_UPSTREAM_PROXY -
```

How can I get this big files upload working without errors?

Answer (score 0):

After multiple research a squid config test I found that it is most probably a bug.
See https://bugs.squid-cache.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5214

The workaround is to set the param `client_request_buffer_max_size` to a value that cover your maximum upload file size, and/or to enable the multi-part feature on your client side, if available.

I ran some tests and didn't noticed any host resource problem even with a value of `100MB`.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, try switching to different clients. It worked for me with cli clients. From a browser, try choosing a different js lib or try to tune parameters where possible (e.g chunks size retries etc.)
I've found out that different client behaved differently. wget from alpine was failing while python "requests" worked fine (on the same container), wget from ubuntu also worked fine.